# Knockout JS object prototype issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

It's not a bug but I can't figure out what's happening.

I want to display a certain set of friends at the page load. And then when the `Add Friend` button is clicked ,

it should add new friends named `SpaceX`. That's happening.

But I can't figure out why it lists a friend named `SpaceX` at the load also.

here is the code snippet.

**View-HTML**

```
<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

<ul data-bind="foreach:friends">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: friendName"></strong>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: knowJS" />
        <input data-bind="value: favLib,visible: knowJS" />
        <button data-bind="click: removeFriend">X</button>
    </li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: addFriend('SpaceX')">Add Friend</button>
```

**ViewModel - JavaScript**

```
//Create a sample JS Class
function Friend(name) {
    this.friendName = name;
    this.knowJS = ko.observable(false);
    this.favLib = ko.observable('');
    this.removeFriend = function() {
        obj.friends.remove(this);
    };
};

// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI

//Create an object type using constructor function
function AppViewModel(){
    this.friends = ko.observableArray([new Friend("Chiranjib"), new Friend("Nandy")]);
};

//Add a property to the prototype of the object type
AppViewModel.prototype.addFriend= function(fname){
    this.friends.push(new Friend(fname));
};

//Create a specific object out of the object type defined
var obj = new AppViewModel();

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(obj);
```

The output at the page load looks like

[image]

But `SpaceX` should only be added when the `Add Freind` button is clicked. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your data binding.  When knockout comes across this during the data-binding step:

```
data-bind="click: addFriend('SpaceX')"
```

It will run it *immediately* and assign the result of the function to the `click` event handler.  If you need to pass parameters to a bound function in this way, you need to wrap it in another function:

```
data-bind="click: function() { addFriend('SpaceX'); }"
```

This anonymous function is then bound to the `click` event, and `addFriend` won't be called until you actually click the button.

Comment: does it mean click events should ideally be called like the way you showed . Otherwise it might well be a mess , right ?

Comment: Avoid creating functions in your binding code. It's bad style. It's better to reference functions your viewmodel already has.

Comment: Not at all - You might have a different input box that you bind to `newFriendName = ko.observable()`, then make use of that within your `addFriend` event handler, which you can now bind directly to the click function.  Ideally you want your view to be as clean as possible.